# FPDF - Can it handle original PDF with mixed orientations (portrait/landscape)?

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I am using the FPDF() method (from FPDI_Protection.php) to import existing PDFs and apply password protection.

The problem I'm having is that the original PDF has a mix of portrait and landscape pages (8.5"X11" & 11"X8.5"), whereas the import method makes you define it once.  I can define the newly created pdf to be 11"X11", which fixes the problem of one of the orientations cropping, but this is not ideal for printing purposes, as the PDF is scaled and left aligned, causing poor readability/printout.

Is there any sort of routine I could use, as the original document is being looped through, to detect the original size and set the new page orientation on the fly?

```
function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile)  // RESPONSIBLE FOR ADDING PASSWORD PROTECTION TO PDF FILES
{
    require_once('fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php');

    $pdf = new FPDI_Protection();
    // set the format of the destinaton file, in our case 6×9 inch
    $pdf->FPDF('P', 'in', array('11','11'));

    //calculate the number of pages from the original document
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

    // copy all pages from the old unprotected pdf in the new one
    for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++)
    {
        $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
        $pdf->addPage();
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
    }

    // protect the new pdf file, and allow no printing, copy etc and leave only reading allowed
    $pdf->SetProtection(array('print'), $password, '');
    $pdf->Output($destFile, 'F');

    return $destFile;
}
```

Or, alternatively, is there a simpler way to add a password to an existing pdf using php?

Comment: One thing I'd try is running the slightly modified code against TCPDF. It's written by the same guy but updated regularly.

Comment: @mkaatman - I'm pretty lost with this suggestion.  It seems to me that TCPDF requires you to define a single size at construction in the same way this does.

Comment: I was hoping the import would be more graceful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I pulled my hair out for days on this one.  After tireless googling every iteration of terms related to my problem I was able to find one instance of a solution that actually worked (I tried installing pdflib lite, phpinfo, ghostscript, xpdf, etc. etc., to measure dimensions to no avail).  What worked was this (you need the [FPDI_Protection package](http://www.setasign.de/supra/kon2_dl/34141/FPDI_Protection-1.0.4.zip) [free]):

```
    $specs = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplidx);
    $pdf->addPage($specs['h'] > $specs['w'] ? 'P' : 'L');
```

The full function is as follows:

```
function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile)  // RESPONSIBLE FOR ADDING PASSWORD PROTECTION TO PDF FILES
{
    require_once('fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php');

    $pdf = new FPDI_Protection();
    // set the format of the destinaton file
    $pdf->FPDF('P', 'in', array('8.5','11'));

    //calculate the number of pages from the original document
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

    // copy all pages from the old unprotected pdf in the new one
    for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++)
    {

        $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);

        $specs = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplidx);
        $pdf->addPage($specs['h'] > $specs['w'] ? 'P' : 'L');
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
    }

    // protect the new pdf file

    $pdf->SetProtection(array('print'), $password, '');
    $pdf->Output($destFile, 'F');

    return $destFile;
}
```

The addition of those two lines of code was able to detect whether the original page was portrait of landscape, and recreate the page in the output file the same way.  Hallelujah.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to change the page layout from landscape to portrait ?

Comment: The original documents are hundreds of pages long and contain mixed orientations.  I wanted to know if FPDF could handle this properly when loading in the original and spitting out a secure version, which it can, using the answer I found above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your posting, I could solve my orientation problem within a minute!

Anyway, you do not need the  special FPDI_"Protection" package for the orientation change alone, a working solution only needs the "FPDI" package (for the getTemplatesize function).
Here is a link to the solution from August 2012:
[FPDF / FPDI addPage() Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185777/fpdf-fpdi-addpage-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

In my fpdf_tpl.php (1.6.1) the method to add pages is called **AddPage** not addPage. Take a look that if you call addPage the  method isn't executed and you can't change the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

To use getTemplateSize you only need [setasign/fpdi](https://packagist.org/packages/setasign/fpdi) package.
For the current version of this package (**v2.3.6**), the height and width keys are not 'w' and 'h' anymore but 'width' and 'height':

(from setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi.php)

```
/**
 * Get the size of an imported page or template.
 *
 * Give only one of the size parameters (width, height) to calculate the other one automatically in view to the
 * aspect ratio.
 *
 * @param mixed $tpl The template id
 * @param float|int|null $width The width.
 * @param float|int|null $height The height.
 * @return array|bool An array with following keys: width, height, 0 (=width), 1 (=height), orientation (L or P)
 */
public function getTemplateSize($tpl, $width = null, $height = null)
{
    ...
}
```